# Tomcat 8 virtual host as case insensitive

Tags: java, virtualhost, tomcat8

Can we make virtual host on tomcat 8 work in case insensitive manner?
If we are making virtual host using context in conf/catalina/localhost

Answer (score 0):

DNS names are case-insensitive, so foo.acme.com is identical to Foo.Acme.Com and all other possible combinations.
For that reason Tomcat treats hostnames case-insensitive, too.

So suppose you've got a Virtual Host named "foo" and your tomcat is listening on port 8080 `curl localhost:8080 -H "Host: foo"` will hit the same app as `curl localhost:8080 -H "Host: Foo"` or `curl localhost:8080 -H "Host: fOO"`